# How to show tables that match certain strings in databricks

Tags: sql, schema, databricks

Using

```
SHOW TABLES in mydatabase
```

gives me a list of all included tables. Like

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| database | tableName  | comment |
+----------+------------+---------+
|    db1   |   table1   |   null  |
|    db1   |   table2   |   null  |  
|    db1   | table_trkw |   null  |         |
```

I just want to get the tables that include a specific string, say "*trkw*"

When using

```
SHOW TABLES in db1 WHERE tableName IN ('%trkw%');
```

Or

```
SHOW TABLES in db1 WHERE tableName LIKE '%trkw%';
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: mismatched input WHERE' expecting <EOF>
```

I just don't get what's wrong with the WHERE condition. Is it because the WHERE condition can't be used on database, but just on its tables?

How can I filter the tables that include '*trkw*'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM mydatabase LIKE '*trkw*'
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it's returning: "Query returned no results"

Comment: I am no expert of databricks but this should work. Is there a table like trkw?

Comment: yes, the database consists of 179 tables and 33 do have "_trkw_", like gmsgqgq_kpi_site_mapping_trkw_glbl.

Comment: I tried various forms: ...like 'trkw'; or ...like "%trkw%"; These 2 result in "Query returned no results"; When including ( it says: "Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
extraneous input '(' expecting STRING"

Comment: Does SHOW TABLES in db1 show any table where name like trkw?

Comment: Found a link https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-tables.html

Comment: Thanks, got it; See the example from the link: SHOW TABLES FROM default LIKE 'sam*'; The solution are the **. So in my case it's '*trkw*'. Edit your answer so I can mark it as answered, if you like.

Comment: That's great. Congrates! Best wishes.

Comment: * missing after the w.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Best wishes.